# Export data from SQL and write to etxt file (No BCP or SP can be used)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, export

So I'm looking for an easy way to export data from a SQL Server 2000 database and write it to a comma delimited text file. Its one table and only about 1,000 rows. I'm new to C# so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

Comment: perhaps try searching for examples and come back with a specific problem. This shows no thought whatsoever.

Comment: I've looked for examples and everything that comes up has to do with Store procs, xp_cmdshell / BCP or even SSIS/SSRS. 

I know how to do this through BCP but for the life of me I'm at a loss when it comes to C#

Answer (score 7):

This is a very easy task, but you need to learn the SqlClient namespace and the different objects you have at your disposal. You will want to note though that for SQL Server 2000 and lower asynchronous methods are not supported, so they will be all blocking.

Mind you this is a very sketchy example, and I did not test this, but this would be one general approach.

```
string connectionString = "<yourconnectionstringhere>";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex) {
        // handle
        return;
    }
    string selectCommandText = "SELECT * FROM <yourtable>";
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, connection)) {
        using (DataTable table = new DataTable("<yourtable>")) {
            adapter.Fill(table);
            StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new StringBuilder();
            commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
                string value = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", row[0], row[1], row[2]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)
                commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
            }
            File.WriteAllText("<pathhere>", commaDelimitedText.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Some resources you will want to look into:

- SqlConnection Class; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=VS.90).aspx
- SqlDataAdapter Class; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds404w5w(v=VS.90).aspx
- SqlDataAdapter.Fill Method; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=VS.90).aspx
- DataTable Class; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

I'm also not sure what your requirements are, or why you have to do this task, but there are also probably quite a lot of tools out there that can already do this for you (if this is a one time thing), because this is not an uncommon task.

Comment: Okay, thanks the the info... I agree, I'm not sure as to why this fell on my plate but it has so I'm just going to use it as a learning experience. As for how often we do this... almost never...

Answer (score 0):

This is no different in C# than in any other language with the tools you need.

1) Query DB and store data in collection
2) Write collection to file in CSV format

Comment: C# is completely new to me... can you point me to a site that might have a simple tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a Windows Form application?  If you have bound data to a control such as a DataGridView this is pretty easy to do.  You can just loop through the control and write the file that way.  I like this because if you implemented filtering mechanisms in your application, whatever a user filtered can be written to the file.  This is how I have done this before.  You should be able to tweak this if you are using some sort of collection without much trouble.

```
private void exportCsv()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        createSaveDialog(saveFile, ".csv", "CSV (*csv)|*.csv)");
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName);
        int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int col = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;

        try
        {
            if (saveFile.FileName != "")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    writer.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText + ",");
                }

                writer.Write("\r\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < row - 1; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < col - 1; k++)
                    {
                        writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Value.ToString() + ",");
                    }
                    writer.Write("\r\n");
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("File Sucessfully Created!", "File Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File could not be created.", "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            saveFile.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I haven't even started since I'm more of a db guys. (So no on the windows application form) They just said here... we need it in C# and need it by end of next week. I love learning new things but without a place to start its a huge pain.