# Retrieve data from Mysql to excel macro, Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I have no idea about excel macro. I need to get the data from MySQL and display it in excel. Can i get any links or code examples for this.

Comment: Same question like that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816918/how-to-export-sql-server-data-to-excel-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: i need to use macro to get data from mysql to excel.

Comment: check this if not helpful then use google. http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?135-Retrieve-Data-From-A-Database-To-Excel-Using-SQL

Comment: Tats too complicate. Anyways i found the ans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer() 
  Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection 
  Dim Server_Name As String 
  Dim Database_Name As String 
  Dim User_ID As String 
  Dim Password As String 
  Dim SQLStr As String 
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 

Server_Name = "" ' Enter your server name here
Database_Name = "" ' Enter your database name here
User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
Password = "" ' Enter your password here
SQLStr = "select Period, Secured, Unsecured from cmisa.credit_facts" 

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection 
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _ 
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";" 

rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic 
 ' Dump to spreadsheet
With Worksheets("1.Overview").Range("AI7:AK19") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
    .ClearContents 
    .CopyFromRecordset rs 
End With 
 ' Tidy up
rs.Close 
Set rs = Nothing 
Cn.Close 
Set Cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

if want to view data, you can use myODBC to connect exel, read http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/Using-Excel-to-analyze-MySQL-data

register member before read fully